# Create union of unique array items from union of types (typescript)

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

I'd like to ask, is it possible to declare an array of unique types from union of those types?

I have this type `Value`:

```
type Value = string | number
```

Then I created type `Values` like this:

```
type Values = Value[]
```

but that creates a type:

```
type Values = (string|number)[]
```

but how can I achieve this from the type `Value`?

```
type Values = string[] | number[]
```

Because basically I have a function that renders `checkbox`-es for table filters. That `checkbox` will always have either `string` or `number` as a value.

Then when you click on a checkbox, it adds that value to an array. For example, you have a column `firstName` and you add two names to that filter. It then becomes an array of `string` or array of `number`: `string[] | number[]` which would represent my type `Values`.

So is there a way to create type `Values` from type `Value`?

I created this sample [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-tdd-8zg3x?file=/src/index.ts) just to compare those types.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These solutions are not satisfactory to me.  In the first case, I must explicitly mention the type of element I'm expecting in the array.  In the second, I must enumerate all array types I'm interested in (what I'm trying to avoid in the first place!  Besides, *I have the union type, I want the array types* - it's not a matter of preference)

Anyways, after playing around a bit I figured out one way to make it work.  Then I went back to [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and realized that they actually use this exact problem as an example...

```js
type ValueTypes = string | number
type ToArray<Type> = Type extends any ? Type[] : never;

const a1: ToArray<ValueTypes> = ['a','b'] // okay
const a2: ToArray<ValueTypes> = [1, 2]    // okay
const a3: ToArray<ValueTypes> = ['a', 2]  // error (i.e. success)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would choose of restricted templating

```
type Values<T extends string | number> = T[];

const myArr: Values<string> = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
];

const myArr2: Values<number> = [
    1,
    2,
];
```

---

Or use overloaded types *(let typescript decide the type depending on what's inside of the array)*

```
type ValueTypeA = string[];
type ValueTypeB = number[];

type Values = ValueTypeA | ValueTypeB;

const myArr: Values = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
];

const myArr2: Values = [
    1,
    2,
];
```